# Eigensubspaces of commuting matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Symmetric matrices $n\times n$ $A$ and $B$ commute ($AB=BA$), then they have common basis in which both are diagonolized. If $A$ has eigenvalue $a$ with corresponding eigenvectors - $X$ ($AX=aX$) that span $k$-dimensional subspace - eigensubspace (i.e. $a$ has order $k$ - I don't rememeber how to say correctly: order or degree. What I mean it is that same eigenvalue is repeated several times).

Question: Will the same subspace be eigensubspace of $B$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That dimension $k$ is usually called the geometric multiplicity of $a$ (same as algebraic multiplicity for symmetric matrices).

The answer is no: consider an $n\times n$ identity matrix (the eigenspace associated with the only eigenvalue $1$ is the whole $\mathbb{C}^n$) and an $n\times n$ diagonal matrix with distinct diagonal entries (and hence the distinct eigenvalues; the eigenspaces have dimension 1).

Comment: If A has all its eigenvalues distinct, then every matrix commutes with A is simple.
Proposition 2: Simple matrices A and X commute if and only if they have a set of n linearly independent eigenvectors is common. In other words, if A and X are simple and AX = XA, then there exists a basis consisting entirely of common eigenvectors of A and X.
[1] Lancaster P., Tismenetsky M.,  The theory of Matrices Second Edition with Applications, New York, 1985.p.420
Question: from this follows that matrices can have common eigen subspaces? (can you give another contr-example but not using identity matrix?)

Comment: $\mathrm{diag}(1,1,1,2,2,2)$ and $\mathrm{diag}(1,1,2,2,3,3)$. Also any similarity transformation thereof (with a fixed basis for both of course).